# Super filter attribuites to display as dropdown instead of checkbox

Tags: php, opencart

I am using Opencart 2.2.0 on Journal theme. I am using super filter to display attributes. The problem is - this filter only displays as check box. I need it to display as drop down. The theme maker told me that module only shows in check box option, but I am wondering if I can make it display as drop down instead.  The code for super_filter_attributes.tpl is:

```
<div class="box sf-attribute sf-attribute-<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?> sf-<?php echo $attribute['type']; ?>">
<div class="box-heading"><?php echo $attribute['attribute_name']; ?></div>
<div class="box-content">
    <ul class="<?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('filter_show_box') ? '' : 'hide-checkbox'; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($attribute['values'] as $value) { ?>
        <li><label><input data-keyword="<?php echo $value['keyword']?>" type="checkbox" name="attribute[<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']?>]" value="<?php echo $value['text']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I edited a bit and now my code looks like this:

```
<div class="box sf-attribute sf-attribute-<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?> sf-<?php echo $attribute['type']; ?>">
<div class="box-heading"><?php echo $attribute['attribute_name']; ?></div>
<div class="box-content">
    <ul class="<?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('filter_show_box') ? '' : 'hide-checkbox'; ?>">
       <div class="box sf-attribute sf-attribute-<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?> sf-<?php echo $attribute['type']; ?>">
<div class="box-heading"><?php echo $attribute['attribute_name']; ?></div>
<div class="box-content">
    <ul class="<?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('filter_show_box') ? '' : 'hide-checkbox'; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($attribute['values'] as $value) { ?>
        <select>
         <option><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
          <?php foreach ($value['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
          <?php if (in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" selected>
         <?php echo $filter['name']; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>">
         <?php echo $filter['name']; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am not doing everything good, because I can see only partial drop down now, and all is mixed up.
Any suggestions to edit my code? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Put select tag outside foreach. This may help.

```
<select> <?php foreach ($attribute['values'] as $value) { ?>

         <option><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
          <?php foreach ($value['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
          <?php if (in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" selected>
         <?php echo $filter['name']; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>">
         <?php echo $filter['name']; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>


        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanx for your reply. I tried this, but it is not helping. It stays the same.

Comment: They appear nested in each other.

Comment: Also you shouldn't put select tags inside ul tag. May be that caused the issue.

Comment: I removed ul, still the same. I am desperate!

Comment: Can you please share the screen shot which type of view you are getting ?

Comment: Hi, i don't know how to add screenshot in comment.